# How to fix two circuits in one junction box sharing the same neutral?

Tags: wiring

I recently purchased an older house and in doing renovations have run into a situation where two circuits (wired with 14/2) are present in one junction box and all neutrals are tied together.  I understand that this was an accepted practice at some point but no longer code compliant for obvious reasons.  My question is how do I rectify the situation without tearing the house apart.

My research suggests that I can replace the two existing 15 amp breakers with a new two pole 15 amp breaker.  However I'm unsure as to how this should be wired into the box.  The two pole breakers that I have been able to find all have just one connection for a neutral as they are produced assuming the use of 3 wire in a new application.  In my case, there are two neutrals needing to tie into the breaker.  Would it be correct and code compliant to tie the two neutrals together within the panel box and then pigtail to the new two pole breaker?

Comment: Presumably this is a problem because you're using arc-fault breakers?

Comment: Yes, using arc-fault

Comment: Is how many places are the two neutrals of these two circuits tied together?

Comment: Is it the case that throughout the house in every box where two circuits cross that the neutrals are tied together?

Comment: Fortunately I have not run into this situation in other areas of the house at this point.

Comment: Jim - They are tied together in one location.

Comment: AFIK one always uses 14-3 to connect the two switches to each other. So there should be a red wire. Is there one? If the electrician did not have any 14-3, then he would have to use two lengths of 14-2 to get an extra wire, and then not use one of the wires in the "extra" length of cable. This could cause confusion due to no color difference. Is the line power to the light coming into the box for the light or the box for one of the switches?

Comment: I believe it is coming into the box for the other switch (that being the switch where the neutral is not tied into the neutrals from another circuit).  Are you saying that there may be an extra wire that is unused and entirely in this situation?  If so, how would you identify?

Comment: I am not an experienced troubleshooting electrician. I have not seen or even thought about how one could mis-wire circuits. I am just just now imagining how one could wire this kind of circuit without using 14-3  (white, black, red color coded wires).  Look at the terminals of both switches. Call switch #1 the one where you think the line power is coming into the box. What is the color of the wire on the common terminal and what are the colors of the wires on the two others? Call the other switch #2. What is the color of the wire on the common terminal and what on the other two?

Comment: All the switching in a circuit with two 3-way switches controlling one load is supposed to be in the hot side. However, some of the wires in these connections can be white although they are supposed to be marked with black tape or marker. In this case one will have a white which is (sometimes) hot. Another white wire will be the neutral (not hot ever) and this will go directly to the neutral terminal of the  light fixture. The black line hot (always hot) will go to the common of the switch #1. A wire (usu black) from the common of #2 goes directly to the load.

Answer (score 1):

If the two circuits are wired with 14-2, all you need to do is identify which neutral goes with which circuit and disconnect them from each other, so each is only connected to the items on its circuit.

This would only be a problem if the two circuits were actually sharing a neutral wire. If they simply have joined neutrals, it's easy to remedy.

Comment: One of the switches in this box is a three way switch where one of the neutrals was used in the wiring of the 3-way.  This is leaving just one remaining neutral wire on that circuit with no other neutral to tie to.   Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong?

Comment: @confused - Not totally wrong the white wire you are talking about is being used as a switch leg or a carrier. If you can you should mark it by wrapping it in black tape to identify it is not a neutral.